# SOCKET.IO index.js:83 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsArrayBuffer' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'

Tags: socket.io, typeerror

I have a problem which seems impossible for me to debug, and even if i was able to, i still can't find a way to fix it. Here is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsArrayBuffer' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.
at n (index.js:83)
at n (index.js:83)
at n (index.js:83)
at n (index.js:83)
at n (index.js:83)
at n (index.js:83)
at Object.e.removeBlobs (index.js:83)
at s (index.js:83)
at r.encode (index.js:83)
at r.packet (index.js:83)
```

I am using Socket.IO version 2.1.1 and Google Chrome. I am also using Node and npm.
These are the imports in the index.html file that are related to socketio:
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.js"
Can anyone tell me a solution to this?